# How can I get readable OCR content based on the video timeline from the Insights JSON output

Tags: azure, ocr, azure-video-indexer, azure-ai

I am new to Azure Video Indexer and I want to have the transcript interspersed with the OCR content based on the timeline. Exactly as is shown on the VideoIndexer screen when those 2 options are checked. It seems I can only get either just the transcript, or the entire JSON file with all the insights and the OCR content is broken up into many unreadable pieces

When I get the full insights, it does not help me. But somehow on the Indexer screen it is displayed in really nice format, broken up by the transcription timeline and giving the transcript a nice flow along with the relevant OCR content